# What is GroupScope?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving, ssreflect

In all of the coq codes in ssreflect there is this statement

```
Import GroupScope.
```

What is `GroupScope`? If it is another file, where can I download it from?

Answer (score 2):

`GroupScope`  is a module defined in the [fingroup](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/~jenkins/current/Ssreflect.fingroup.html) module of the [MathComp](http://ssr.msr-inria.inria.fr/doc/mathcomp-1.5/) library (formerly, a part of SSR). It is defined as follows:

```
Module GroupScope.
Open Scope group_scope.
End GroupScope.
```

Thus, importing `GroupScope` has the effect of making all notations in `group_scope` available to the current file, with one small difference, as explained in the source code:

> This module can be imported to open the scope for group element 
>    operations locally to a file, without exporing the Open to clients of that file (as Open would do).